# Encryption and decryption on special symbol Python

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, utf-8

```
test = '\x02m@\x0e\x00'
print(test)
print(test.replace('╗m@', "first"))
new_test = test.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')
print(new_test)
print(new_test.replace('╗m@', "second"))
again_new = new_test.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')
print(again_new)
print(again_new.replace('╗m@', "third"))
```

I have been trying to decrypt some files that was originally encrypt via VB.Net using python 3.6; the file was encrypted with the public key before encoding to base 64. I have tried numerous way to decode base 64 and decrypt it with the private key that was given but, I would always have some special character such as '╗m@' that could not be remove even after I tried to manually remove them.

I have also tried to decode via 'utf-8' and 'ascii' but to no avail. I have tried looking around and some have told me that it looks like a double encoded string but, I can't seem to be able to replace the string even after decoding twice.

From what I know, '\x02m@\x0e\x00' would return '╗m@' when running. A string cannot decode directly thus, I made use of 'raw_unicode_escape' to change the string into a byte object before decoding.

If someone can point out in which direction I should be heading, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import base64
import codecs
import re

# reading private key 
rsa_key = RSA.importKey(open('PrivateKey.pem', 'r').read())

# reading the file that is suppose to be decrypted
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
message = file.read()

# decode base64 first
decrypted_body = base64.b64decode(message)
print(decrypted_body)

# have to make it bytearray if not, it would not be able to concat with the decrypted chunk
final_decrypted = bytearray()

# size of the chunk to decrypt
chunk_size = 128
offset = 0

# maximum length of the body that has to be decrypted
limit = len(decrypted_body)

# there is a need to check the length that has to be decrypted so as to not overshot during the last iteration
while offset < len(decrypted_body):
    if (offset + chunk_size > limit):
        copyLength = limit
    else:
        copyLength = offset + chunk_size

    chunk = decrypted_body[offset: copyLength]

    final_decrypted += rsa_key.decrypt(chunk)

    offset += chunk_size

# decode the result to utf-8 to remove bytes that can't be read
xml_decrypted = codecs.decode(final_decrypted, encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore')

break_loop = False
remove_arr = []
# pattern to find the special character in what was decoded
pattern = re.compile('[^0-9a-zA-Z<>_=\"?. -/@:™{^\\r}{^\\n}]+')
for i in range(0, len(xml_decrypted)):
    if (pattern.match(xml_decrypted[i])):
        arr = []
        arr.append(xml_decrypted[i])
        # \x00 refer to " " thus, I do not want to remove it as it would make the xml harder to read
        # this is to append all the special symbol into an array 
        while (xml_decrypted[i] != '\x00' and i < len(xml_decrypted)):
            n = i
            i += 1
            if (i < len(xml_decrypted)):
                arr.append(xml_decrypted[i])
            else:
                break_loop = True
                break

        remove_str = "".join(arr)
        remove_arr.append(remove_str)
        i = n
        if (break_loop):
            break

# check if the array has any " " inside as there is no need to remove space from the xml result
# remove each of the result inside the array from the decoded result which will hopefully return me the xml without any special symbol
new_str = ""
remove_arr = [x for x in remove_arr if x != '\x00']
for each in remove_arr:
    print(str(each))
    new_str = xml_decrypted.replace(each, '')
    xml_decrypted = new_str

print(xml_decrypted)
```

As requested, I have posted my code here for python 3 but, I am unable to release the VB.Net code as it does not belong to me. Cheers

Comment: Encrypted or encoded? (There is a _huge_ difference.)

Comment: Hi @DYZ , thanks for pointing it out. The original message was encoded via a public key done with VB.Net and I am trying to decode it with the private key using python 3.

Comment: If you have keys then you are encrypting / decrypting. Encoding is the conversion from one format to another. So encoding with a public key doesn't make sense. Your encryption / decryption routines are however missing from the question, please create a MCVE. I have the feeling that you are doing something wrong before the conversion in your question.

Comment: Hi @Maarten Bodewes, I’m sorry for making such mistake. The encryption code was done via VB.Net where they encrypt with the public key first before encoding to base 64. What I did was decode base 64 and decrypt using the private key. There is this part in the VB.Net code where they slice up the file, after converting to bytes, into smaller bytes and encrypt them separately. I have tried to reverse engineer it with python 3 but, to no avail.

Comment: Hi @MaartenBodewes, I have posted my code above as I have no idea how to create a MCVE. So sorry about that.

Comment: `╗` is almost certainly not equivalent to `\x02`. Which encoding have you used for your Python script? Which precise code point is `╗` supposed to represent? Perhaps see also tangentially [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) which has some guidance for this sort of situation.

Comment: A byte is a byte, it is always 8 bits. What do you mean by "smaller bytes"?

Comment: Hi @tripleee, as you can see from my code, the decryption was done in smaller bytes rather than the whole chunk together as it would fetch an error. I believe this is not the usual practice.

Comment: No, it's not clear what you mean. You probably mean a different word, "smaller chunks" perhaps?

Comment: Hi @tripleee, I believed it is correct. I meant smaller chunk of the entire chunk. So sorry for the miscommunication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using raw or textbook RSA. From the [`decrypt`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#decrypt) documentation:

> Attention: this function performs the plain, primitive RSA decryption (textbook). In real applications, you always need to use proper cryptographic padding, and you should not directly decrypt data with this method. Failure to do so may lead to security vulnerabilities. It is recommended to use modules `Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP` or `Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5` instead.

So you are likely forgetting to remove the (largely random) padding from the result. I'd try `PKCS1_v1_5` first.

---

It is highly recommended to use hybrid encryption (e.g. AES / GCM in combination with RSA OAEP) instead of encrypting multiple times with the same RSA key.